# How To Redirect The Same Person (or IP Address) From Spamming Out Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

My company offers free one-time products that a user can request and our team will mail it to the home. The issue is we're having multiple of the same people requesting the free product. It's taking alot of time from our support team to filter out the same user requesting multiple free products.

It'd be great if we could detect the same IP address or use a cookie to detect the same person and re-direct them to a landing page when they click the button to access the form and request the free product.

Comment: What are you using on the back end?  JavaScript and jQuery are both front end technologies and are unlikely to be useful in solving this problem.

Comment: It's a basic HTML website that links to a TypeScript form.

Comment: You don't want to implement this kind of thing in the typescript form then

Comment: What is your suggestion then? It doesn't have to be implemented on the form. There is a basic HTML landing page as well.

Comment: You'll want to modify the server-side script (which you say is typescript) to reject the submission and show an error page.